# Injecting scoped service from singleton service in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a cacheHelper. When I add the dependency of CacheHelper to startup with "AddScoped", it is working. But,`CacheHelper.cs` is running for every request. So, I convert to "AddSingleton" like below. But I'm taking an error, like that:
**Cannot consume scoped service 'MyProject.DataAccess.IUnitOfWork' from singleton 'MyProject.Caching.ICacheHelper'** How can I fix this problem?

Strartup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();
        services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>());
        services.AddSingleton<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

CacheHelper.cs

```
public class CacheHelper : ICacheHelper
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public IMemoryCache Cache { get; }

    public CacheHelper(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        Cache = cache;
    }

    public void SetCommonCacheItems()
    {
        var cities = unitOfWork.CityRepo.GetAll();
        Cache.Set("cities", cities);

        string obj;
        Cache.TryGetValue<string>("cities", out obj);
    }

    public string GetCities()
    {
        string obj;
        Cache.TryGetValue<string>("cities", out obj);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: worth your time to read this: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/

Comment: A Singleton cannot reference a Scoped instance

Comment: Thanks @JohnB. I read now your post. In that post, it advice me adding unitOfWork as singleton. But when I did UnitOfWork as singleton then my request didn't go to server. Where can be mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you had it before was the correct one. `ICacheHelper` should and have to be scoped.

Just your cache implementation is wrong. Get cities will be called, it checks the cache. If not found, it will get the data and put it into the cache.

```
public class CacheHelper : ICacheHelper
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public IMemoryCache Cache { get; }

    public CacheHelper(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        Cache = cache;
    }

    public string GetCities()
    {
        if(!Cache.TryGetValue<string>("cities", string out cities))
        {
            // not found in cache, obtain it
            cities = unitOfWork.CityRepo.GetAll();
            Cache.Set("cities", cities);
        }

        return cities;
    }
}
```

You don't need `SetCommonCacheItems()` method. The important thing is that `IMemoryCache` is static, since it will contain the data. UoW has to be scoped, because of the database, otherwise you would have memory leaks (especially when using EF Core, since its caching/tracking the entities).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tseng. In my idea, everything must be singleton because otherwise requests will be getting slower. So, I tried singleton. But I understand from your reply that there isn't any disadvantage of every service being scoped. Is it true?

Comment: Generally, scoped is the desired way, because otherwise long living services will/may hold memory thats not getting released and your application keeps using more and more memory until it crashes. Classes and their constructors should be fast, if you do something that requires a lot of work in constructor, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks again @Tseng. This is helpful information for me.

Comment: Point is, your UoW has to be scoped, due to the way EF Core and other things work, so you don't save anything or do yourself a favor by making it singleton. IMemoryCache is static anyways. So when `CacheHelper` is constructed only the UoW instanciated (if not already for that request and passed in. `CacheHelper` constructor does nothing but assign it, so its very fast and IMemory cache already exists so only its reference is passed